# How to get the force applied to a link?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello everyone,

I trying to control a quadrotor in gazebo but I'm having some trouble. I'm able to control the velocity of each rotors using a PID+SetForce(), but the quadrotor doens't take off. So, I want to monitor the resulting force applied to the base link of the quadrotor to find the problem, if it doens't fly because I didnt apply a control yet or because the rotors are rotating without applying any force to the body of the quadrotor.

How can I get the resulting force applied to the base link?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18247/how-to-get-the-force-applied-to-a-link?/) by [schulze_18](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4222/schulze_18/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Take a look at [Link::RelativeForce](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/9.0.0/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Link.html#a867129776119e9694eff9d243a5876a1) and [Link::WorldForce](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/9.0.0/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Link.html#a1c24c4c283c25adfda6c0f6754c2fea9)

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2018-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jenny B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/12896/jenny-b/) on 2020-03-31**:
What does Link::RelativeForce return? Does it include forces on the link from downstream links? I'm not seeing that it does.

I'm trying to create a Force/Torque sensor that gives me the external force/torque on a link at the end of a chain.  I'd rather not put a joint there because joints must be between links that have mass in gazebo.